# TYPO3: language dependent variable that is hard-coded in a Fluid template

Tags: typo3, multilingual, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a **multilingual** site built with **TYPO3 V7.6.18**. It uses a slogan which should remain editable but different for three languages. This is a variable that is hard-coded in the Fluid templates.

For variables of this kind I use a file `Configuration/TypoScript/constants.ts` where I define the variable that can be edited (`WEB -> Template -> Constant Editor`) and used:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#   constants.ts
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# customsubcategory=general=General Setup

myextension.configuration {
    general {
        # cat=myextension/general/05; type=string; label=Website Slogan.
        slogan= website slogan in main language
    }
}

[globalVar = GP:L=1]
    myextension.configuration.general.slogan = website slogan in second language
[end]

[globalVar = GP:L=2]
    myextension.configuration.general.slogan = website slogan in third language
[end]
```

I then bind the variable in `Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts` for use:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#   setup.ts
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

page = PAGE
page {
    # Page Main template
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        variables {
            # slogan
            slogan = TEXT
            slogan.value = {$myextension.configuration.general.slogan}
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but only the slogan in the main language is editable ...

Any solution to make the slogans editable in the other two languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend to use language identifiers for the constants instead:

```
myextension.configuration {
    general {
        slogan {
          # cat=myextension/general/05; type=string; label=Website Slogan in default language.
          default = website slogan in main language
          # cat=myextension/general/06; type=string; label=Website Slogan in second language.
          second = website slogan in second language
          # cat=myextension/general/07; type=string; label=Website Slogan in third language.
          third = website slogan in third language
        }
    }
}
```

Then move the condition to the setup:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    # Page Main template
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        variables {
            # slogan
            slogan = TEXT
            slogan.value = {$myextension.configuration.general.slogan.default}
        }
    }
}

[globalVar = GP:L=1]
    page.10.variables.slogan.value = {$myextension.configuration.general.slogan.second}
[end]

[globalVar = GP:L=2]
    page.10.variables.slogan.value = {$myextension.configuration.general.slogan.third}
[end]
```

Comment: ciao mathias !! could you add the code for the setup ... then your answer is accepted !

Comment: I would use a label in locallang.xlf file; IMO it can be mantained better

Comment: Ciao Riccardo !! I would not grant access to an editor to the xlf file !! furthermore its way to tecnical to propose, I'm testing now what mathias proposed ... that's where an editor should expect a setting like that

Comment: @Mathias Brodala this has worked fine, in V11 it doesn't ... any clue's ?

Comment: You could update the condition to use [siteLanguage()](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#sitelanguage) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Three possibilities suggest themselves, two of which were mentioned by Mathias and Riccardo. I‘ll add a third one an list pros and cons of them.

So, firstly the third possibility which is to create a content element (preferably of type `header`) and create a TypoScript constant holding its `uid`.

```
# cat=myextension/general/05; type=int; label=Slogan CE UID
myextension.configuration.general.sloganUid =
```

Then fetch this content element‘s header in your fluid variable:

```
page.10.variables.slogan = CONTENT
page.10.variables.slogan {
    select.uidInList = {$myextension.configuration.general.sloganUid}
    table = tt_content
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = header
}
```

Create a sysfolder, create a content element of type header and plumb its uid in your constant. Maybe you‘ll have to add some more stuff to `.select` to make it work - I‘m always unsure that.

Now pros and cons:

#### **Three constants**, as suggested by Mathias:

- **pro**: Closed to what you did, easy, little code, no file access needed for changes
- **con**: need to add another constant to constants and setup for each additional language

#### **locallang.xlf**:

- **pro**: That‘s where you expect translations (in code), easy to add translations, can go to VCS
- **con**: Needs file access to change

#### **Content element**:

- **pro**: Admin can grant access to editors (if they want), easiest to add translations
- **con**: adds DB queries (but normally cached), easy to screw up from BE

Comment: please feel free to edit and add pros and cons, everybody!

Comment: thanks undko, I needed a moment but the answer of mathias was exact, I try to keep it as simple as possible for an editor, that is for me a dominant pro

Comment: thanks for your suggestion though, would I need much more information than one line of header ... I then probabely would adopt your CE solution !!